# How to construct values of a higher-rank Coyoneda type in CPS?

Tags: haskell, unification, higher-rank-types

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Coyoneda f a = Coyoneda {
  uncoyo :: forall b r. ((b -> a) -> f b -> r) -> r
}

coyoneda f tx = Coyoneda (\k -> k f tx)
```

I think `Coyoneda` should work by simulating existentials with a higher-rank type, but I fail to construct values of this type. The `coyoneda` auxiliary function doesn't type check, because with regard to the term `k f tx` the higher-rank type variable `b` would escape its scope.

However, I cannot come up with another way to implement `coyoneda`. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type `T` is isomorphic to

```
forall r . (T -> r) -> r
```

by the Yoneda isomorphism.

In your case,

```
forall b r. ((b -> a) -> f b -> r) -> r
~=  -- adding explicit parentheses
forall b . (forall r. ((b -> a) -> f b -> r) -> r)
~=  -- uncurrying
forall b . (forall r. ((b -> a, f b) -> r) -> r)
~=  -- Yoneda
forall b . (b -> a, f b)
```

which is *not* what you wanted. To use coyoneda, you need to model an *existential* type instead:

```
exists b . (b -> a, f b)
```

So, let's turn this into a `forall`

```
exists b . (b -> a, f b)
~=  -- Yoneda
forall r . ((exists b . (b -> a, f b)) -> r) -> r
~=  -- exists on the left side of -> becomes a forall
forall r . (forall b . (b -> a, f b) -> r) -> r
~=  -- currying
forall r . (forall b . (b -> a) -> f b -> r) -> r
```

Hence, this is the correct encoding you need to use in your `Coyoneda` definition.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `newtype` is not quite correct. The following works:

```
newtype Coyoneda f a = Coyoneda {
  uncoyo :: forall r. (forall b. (b -> a) -> f b -> r) -> r
}

coyoneda f g = Coyoneda (\k -> k f g)
```

Comment: I've just found this out myself reading [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types#Relation_to_Existentials)